# Scala case class with argument type change at runtime

Tags: scala

Scala Issue:
JSON data is extracted and stored into case class, the time string data needs to be converted to sql timestamp for
Spark dataframe and to Java/Joda Date for Salat DAO/Mongo DB store.

And both don't support each other format.

Currently we are using two case class for same:

```
case class A(a:int,  b:string, time:java.sql.timestamp)
case class B(a:int, b:string, time:java.util.Date)
```

So an Json Extractor method populates either of the above two case class based on the store type Spark/Mongo

Is there a better way to handle this ? (composite class is one way but again it gets too nested)

Do Note, the case class can even be Nested, (A containing C and D, which in turn can have time arguments within them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think about the application domain first. `Timestamp` or `Date` is an implementation detail depending on your data store.

My suggested solution would be

```
case class MyDomainObject(a: Int, b: String, time: java.util.Instant)

object MyDomainObject {
  def fromMongoObject(o: MyDomainMongoObject): MyDomainObject = ???
  def fromSparkObject(o: MyDomainSparkObject): MyDomainObject = ???
}
```

(NOTE, I picked `java.util.Instant` as an example, you can choose whatever time representation you prefer)

And the classes/functions that deal with Mongo/Spark will extract object respectively in `MyDomainMongoObject` and `MyDomainSparkObject`, that will be then converted using the methods in the companion object. This way you keep your domain clean by thinking only about one particular type of time representation, but every datastore adapter can use its own type.

Comment: Thanks ! But the issue that I might get into is when case class has nested element seq. I need to iterate through each and then do the conversion which would become exhaustive with large data sets. For e.g. case class A(a: Int, b: String, time: java.util.Instant, seq[B]) case class B(a:int, b:string, time:java.util.Instant)  , So in this case the adapter needs to first convert on seq B and then A to get it in proper format. Is my understanding correct here ? Or Am I missing something ? Appreciate your response !!